# Solving an integral including a plus distribution.

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, divergence-operator

I am trying to solve
\begin{equation}\int_0^1 \text{d}x \left(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x}\right)_+,\end{equation}
where the plus should represent a plus distribution. For a plus distribution $T_{[f(x)]_+}$ I have the following:
$$T_{[f(x)]_+}[\varphi]\equiv \int_0^1 f(x)[\varphi(x)-\varphi(1)]\text{d}x.$$
Now I am not quite sure how to understand the notation of the integral I am trying to solve. Furthermore, it seems that this integral would diverge. However, I tried to solve it with the substitution $x=u-1$ and came up with the following:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \text{d}x \frac{1+x^2}{1-x}&=\int_1^2 \frac{1+(u-1)^2}{1-u+1}\text{d}u\\
&=\int_1^2\frac{2+u^2-2u}{-u}\text{d}u\\
&=-2\log u -\frac{u^2}{2}+2u\bigg|_1^2\\
&=-\log 4+\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
Does this make sense? How else can I interpret the notation of this integral?

Comment: By "plus distribution" do you mean the positive part? I've never heard the term.

Comment: Maybe you should more explicitly write out what functional $f$ you're applying to what test function $\phi$. Then you should be able to just plug $\phi$ into the definition of $f$. A valid definition should work for any $\phi$.
If your distribution $f$ is defined as
$$(f, \phi) = \int_0^1 \frac {\phi(x) - \phi(1)} {x-1} dx,$$
and you're applying it to $\phi(x)=x^2+1$, you obtain
$$(f, x^2+1) = \int_0^1 \frac {x^2+1-2} {x-1} dx = \frac 3 2.$$
But if your distribution is
$$(f, \phi) = \int_0^1 \frac {x^2+1} {x-1} (\phi(x) - \phi(1)) dx,$$
then applying it to $\phi(x)=1$ gives zero.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta A **plus distribution** is often used in quantum chromodynamics (QCD) calculations, see for example equation (21) in this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-016-4131-8).

Comment: Therefore I suggest moving this question to the corresponding physics site.

Comment: @zyy It's too old for migration (there's a technical restriction), but I agree that the question can be reasked on Physics SE (with links both ways). Either way, adding a brief description of what the objects in the question mean help anyone who might answer, in part by indicating the understanding the OP has.